# Is there a way to distribute a derivative into a product of arbitrary bounds like a summation?

Tags: derivatives, products

What I am interested in is

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\prod_{a=1}^{b}f_{a}(x). $$
I know that a derivative can easily be distributed into a summation, but what about an arbitrary product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using product rule, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{a=1}^b f_a(x)  = \sum_{a=1}^b \left(\frac{d}{dx} f_a(x) \right)\prod_{j \ne a}f_j(x)$$

Comment: If this is an infinite product, for which functions can we do this and what are assumptions which make the right hand side convergent? Just for curiosity.

Comment: oh, I am assuming finite product. I am not sure about infinite product.

Comment: Do you mind proving that? There are ways I can play around with a product and sum to reasonably assume that form from my own interpretation, but I have never seen anyone actually prove how the product rule works for any number of factors, only 2 or 3.

Comment: try using mathematical induction, treat $k$ product as a term as an intermediate step.

Comment: So what is the j here? Does it count at the same time as a? Is it part of the sum?

Comment: yup, it is part of the time. it is like $f'_1f_2f_3 + f_1f_2'f_3+f_1f_2f_3'$ for the first term, the product term is describing $f_2f_3$.